# Setting up Apollo in Next Js 13

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, next.js13

I have been following these steps to set this up and so far the server pages are fine and being rendered, however the client pages are giving me a 404 of the graphql request and is pointing at localhost:4200/graphql rather the contentful graphql api url set in the wrapper.

I am new to appolo so i ma having trouble debugging. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

apollo-wrapper.tsx

```
'use client';

// ^ this file needs the "use client" pragma

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr';

const { GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN } = process.env;

// have a function to create a client for you
export function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    headers: {
      authorization: CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN ? `Bearer ${CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}` : '',
    },
    fetchOptions: { cache: 'no-store' },
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    // use the `NextSSRInMemoryCache`, not the normal `InMemoryCache`
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            // in a SSR environment, if you use multipart features like
            // @defer, you need to decide how to handle these.
            // This strips all interfaces with a `@defer` directive from your queries.
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

// you need to create a component to wrap your app in
export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>{children}</ApolloNextAppProvider>;
}
```

layout.tsx

```
// import "./globals.css";
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloWrapper } from '@project/graphql';

console.log('ApolloWrapper', ApolloWrapper);

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ApolloWrapper>{children}</ApolloWrapper>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Client component listusers.tsx

```
'use client';

import { gql, useSuspenseQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { GetAllCategoriesQuery } from '@project/graphql';
import React from 'react';

const query = gql`
  query GetAllCategories {
    categoryCollection {
      total
      items {
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function ListUsers() {
  const { data, error } = useSuspenseQuery<GetAllCategoriesQuery>(query);

  return (
    <main style={{ maxWidth: 1200, marginInline: 'auto', padding: 20 }}>
      {error ? (
        <p>Oh no, there was an error</p>
      ) : !data ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : data ? (
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr',
            gap: 20,
          }}
        >
          {data?.categoryCollection?.items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item?.slug} style={{ border: '1px solid #ccc', textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <h3>{item?.title}</h3>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have got this working in worth the server-side and client-side routes, however when i go to the client side i have the expectation of seeing the request in network tab like i was when it was getting a 404 but for some reason it looks to be being made on the server